# How to create unique and safe UID on Admin- Custom Token- Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I use custom auth function on my app, in order to login anonymous users (by saving a unique permanent custom token on their device).

The functions work fine both on app side and admin side but I need to provide a unique UID on the admin side- in order to save the user on Firebase.
Here's my code on Admin (index.js):

```
exports.createToken = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
const uid = "?????"; //  how to create some unique uid here?
return admin.auth()
            .createCustomToken(uid)
            .then(customToken => {
                console.log(`The customToken is: ${customToken}`);
                return {status: 'success', customToken: customToken};
            })

});
```

- I need to create unique uid (that isn't on my Authentication users
  table already).
- It should be "safe" (that two users won't get it at the same time).

Comment: take a look at [nanoid](https://github.com/ai/nanoid)

Comment: Thanks, there's also UUID. But I need some solution for firebase and admin- that would be safe

Comment: Have you considered using Firebase Auth and logging in anonymously?

Comment: Yes, but then it creates multiple anonymous users- multiple tokens. With the custom token I can be sure the device can't create more than 1 user on my db

Comment: anonymous user is more for a temporary login to the system- for example when buying something for a second. I need something that will stay permanent and custom token gives me this option

Comment: Anonymous user accounts are also quite permanent. They are only deleted when you sign out, or when the user uninstalls the app.

Comment: Also posted on https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/516